# Translations API Usage by API Key

Tags: api, monitoring, google-translate

**Here is what I have**:

- Project in Google API (Translate API)
- Billing Enabled
- Upgraded Quota limit up to 10 000 000 chars per day
- One server key
- Many sites, which use this key to translate text

And **here is the problem**: it seems our sites request more texts for translations than we expect and we can't find which of the sites sends so many texts. We have looked at our sites and found nothing. We want to determine translations requests volume by each site or module.

I can see overall usage and quota usage in API Manager. But there is no information about IP / domain name input to the overall usage. Is it possible to see translations usage by site / API usage / other parameter.

**I have some ideas and questions**. First, I can create a unique API key for each site/module so each site will use its own key. But it seems it is not possible to see translations usage by keys within one project.

The second idea was about adding parameter in URL like user_id. That method was mentioned in API docs but, again, I can't see how to generate translations usage by a certain parameter.

**Could you please advise**?

Comment: Maybe have a central function/method in a library that makes the API calls, and log who calls the function?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, we thought about it, but currently we want to solve this problem with Google API manager if we can. BTW its interesting if Google API manager can do what we want

Comment: The API Manager doesn't provide the functionality you're looking for unfortunately. In this case tracking your own usage is the best solution. There is no mention of a user_id parameter or usage tracking in the query parameter reference: https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#query-params.